# Why 2,2-dimethylpropane is not called isopentane?

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature

why 2,2-dimethylpropane is not called isopentane? since 2-methylpropane is called isobutane

Comment: ... because it is not the only isomer of n-pentane.

Comment: It's called neopentane, typically 2-(_mono_)methylalkanes are called _iso_.

Comment: @Mithoron Yes; except the famous “isooctane” which is used for the determination of the octane rating of fuel. This isomer of octane is actually 2,2,4-trimethylpentane.

Comment: @Loong Indeed, calling in isoneo would be complicated ;D

Answer (score 3):

In common nomenclature, the prefix 'iso-' is applied when the chain of carbons is continuous bar one methyl group. The example you provided, 2-methylpropane, is observed to be continuous with exception to one methyl group bound to the central carbon atom.

However, 2,2-dimethylpropane does not feature an analogous structure: because two methyl groups are bound to the central carbon, the same classification is inapplicable. In place, the molecule could be labelled as 'neopentane', in which the prefix specifies a continuous chain excepting two alkyl groups.

[image: Isopentane]

The above image is 2-methylbutane, or isopentane.

[image: Neopentane]

The above-shown image is 2,2-dimethylpropane, or neopentane

If you desire further information concerning the nomenclature, I would advise the following link, from which these images were extracted: http://www.chem.ucla.edu/~harding/IGOC/C/common_name.html

Comment: Which is "isohexane"?  2-methylpentane or 3-methylpentane?  If I am not mistaken "iso-n-ane" is generally applied to 2-methyl-(n-1)-ane.